# NetBeans 6.9 Beta LineWrap

Tags: netbeans, beta

```
-J-Dorg.netbeans.editor.linewrap=true
```

This command, I have read [here](http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=183795), turns the line wrap feature on. What I need to know, however, where can I put this command in order to turn it on? I am using NetBeans 6.9 on Mac OS X 10.6. Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this on the command line when you start NetBeans...

That would look something like this

```
/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans\ 6.9\ Beta.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/bin/netbeans -J-Dorg.netbeans.editor.linewrap=true
```

Or, you can add it to the netbeans_default_options variable in the file

```
Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans\ 6.9\ Beta.app/Contents//Resources/NetBeans/etc/netbeans.conf
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, I have found it. On Mac OS X, you have to control-click the Netbeans app icon, click on 'Show Package Contents', go to Contents/Resources/NetBeans/etc/ and modify the netbeans.conf file.